# Flash player inside a div is moving the whole page wrapper down in IE (why?)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, flash

I placed the **flash player** using: `position: absolute; top: 20; right: 40;` in the div around it.

CSS:

```
#page {
 position: relative;
}
#flashplayer {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 right: 30px;
}
```

(As you can see `#page` is relative)

HTML:

```
<div id="page">
<div id="flashplayer">

<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0" width="300" height="35">
   <param name="movie" value="music_player/player_mini.swf" />
   <param name="quality" value="high" />
   <embed src="music_player/player_mini.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="300" height="35"></embed>
 </object>

</div>
<div id="formfloat">
```

The page: http://ada.kiexpro.com/test/